# How do I close an existing file that I created with my Python script, every time I run said Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my script, I had created a CSV file using Pandas and had it automatically opened using `os.startfile()`. I'm wondering what I need to do to my script to allow this CSV file to close, and then reopen, with the updated information so that I don't have to manually go into Excel and close the file every time I rerun the script.

Every time I run my script, if my `.csv` file is open, I get the following error message:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "filename.csv".

I DON'T get this error message when the file is closed.

Comment: Please publish any code you have so far. If you're not closing the file manually use context manager's `with` syntax.

Comment: I will post this snippet:

> combo_df.to_csv('ModuleD2.csv', index=False)

> os.startfile('ModuleD2.csv')

Comment: Most likely you're neither ever closing the file when you open it, nor using context manager to do it for you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `n = 'other.csv'; df.to_csv(n); os.startfile(n)`

Comment: I found something that works, but I'm not so sure if it's all that efficient. At the beginning of my program, I wrote:

`os.system('taskkill /f /im Excel.exe')`;

`if os.path.exists('ModuleD2.csv') == 'True':
    os.remove('ModuleD2.csv')`

Now, when I run the script, if my original file was open, it "kills" Excel, and deletes my old file, and the lines in my original post, creates a new file, and opens the new file. Really sorry if this is inefficient, I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: [`with`: Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library and should replace `os`.  [Reading and Writing Files in Python (Guide)](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/)